# Python : How to remove backslash from escape character

Tags: python, escaping

I am writing a python code. The code takes a string as input and it assigns a random character to it. The problem with that is sometimes characters like `',(),<>,{},"` gets assigned.
So when I copy the text and assign to another variable, I get an error.

Example: let the text be 'Hello' it might become `QC'?>7`
when I copy the text and assign it in another variable like
`l = "QC\N?7"`

I get the error:
`SyntaxError: (Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1110-1111: malformed \N character escape`

To solve this, I used `re.escape()` to add backslash. So now the text becomes `"QC'\?>7"` but the problem is the N character is lost and I can't convert it back to `'hello'`.

If I add another slash behind '\N' instead of re.escape() i will get `"QC\N?>7"`. But if I want to convert it to 'Hello' again, I need to remove the ''.

How do I remove it?

This is what I did in IDLE-
`l="QC\N?>7"`
`SyntaxError: (Unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: malformed \N character escape`

```
l=re.escape("QC'?>7")
print(l)
```

Output of l is given below
`"QC'\\?>7"`
Now I add '' instead
`l="QC\\N?>7"`
now I want to remove ''
because I need to input as QC\N?>7

Also, I can't replace '' with '' because the '' before 'N' also becomes removed and I can't convert it back to 'hello'

I wanted a code to get past this issue.

Comment: Use a raw string. `l = "QC\N?>7"` should be `l = r"QC\N?>7"`.

Comment: Your question needs an edit to be more readable. What is your intended output in this use-case?

Comment: @journpy I just wanted to know how do i remove the backslash. like a code which would help me do that. But instead i think i can just add raw string character before the variable suggested by.

Comment: OK. Glad it's working now.  Was already typing my answer but needed clarification on what you expect

Comment: Additionally: If you have both `'` and `"` in your value you can use triple quotes to enclose the string (e.g. `r"""that's "somehow" fine"""`). Of course this will fail if those triple quotes are part of the value.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, that's why i actually edited my code in such a way that two or more quotes won't appear next to each other. Thank you